# How to use NSSuperscriptAttributeName for OS X

Tags: nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I can change the font and size but I'm stuck with making text a superscript.

Here is my working code for font and size:

```
aVerseMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: book.verseText,
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)!])
```

Here is what I'm trying for superscript that's not working:

```
aVerseNumberMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verseNumber.description, 
    attributes: [NSSuperscriptAttributeName:NSNumber(1)!])
```

I'm not sure how to do the attributes part to create a superscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName I figured out how to do it the way I showed above. Here are both ways:

**NSSuperscriptAttributeName**

```
aVerseNumberMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verseNumber.description, 
     attributes: [NSSuperscriptAttributeName:NSNumber(int: 2)])
```

**NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName**

```
aVerseNumberMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verseNumber.description, 
     attributes: [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:NSNumber(double: 2.0)])
```