# How to type superscript in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to display the following equation in UILabel. But i don't know how to type the superscript text in xCode.

> 2xˆ3-3xˆ2-36x+2

For reference i use ^ symbol for indicate the superscript.

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios

Answer (score 5):

Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will open a special characters menu. Check if the "Digits — All" category is in the left-hand column. If  it isn't, click the gear icon, then select this category — add it to the list.

See screenshot below
[image]

Comment: Nice trick....This answer solved another issue I had in the back of my mind related to math symbols without using a special math font....

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using NSAttributedString. Following may be of some help:

[How to use NSSuperscriptAttributeName for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059724/how-to-use-nssuperscriptattributename-for-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

For a **simple to use Swift solution**, you might want to checkout **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)**. After importing it into your project (e.g. via Carthage – see instructions in README) you can do something like this:

```
import HandyUIKit

let yourFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
"2x^{3}-3x^{2}-36x+2".superscripted(font: yourFont)
```

The last line will return an `NSAttributedString` which will look exactly like **what you're looking for**. Just **assign it** to a `UILabel`s **`attributedText`** property and **that's it!**

---

If you're looking for **subscripting** a text, simply use `subscripted(font:)` instead. It will recognize structures like `CO_{2}`. There's also `superAndSubscripted(font:)` if you want to combine **both**.

See the [docs](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit#superscriptedfont--subscriptedfont--superandsubscriptedfont) for more information and additional examples.